# Imprimir una variable dentro de una cadena en python

Tags: python-3.x

estoy tratando de hacer una consulta a la base de datos, pero me resulta tedioso el proceso de las comillas simples y dobles dentro del string para en vez de que se muestre como string se muestre el valor de una variable, por ejemplo:

```
nombre = "Jose"

print("mi nombre es nombre nombre");
```

que en vez de que me lo tome como texto me identifique como variable.

Comment: Entiendo que quieres completar completar la frase "Mi nombre es Jose", en ese caso, tienes que poner  ```print ("Mi nombre es ", nombre)```; si es eso lo quieres esa es la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que buscas es formateo de cadenas. Si usas Python >= 3.6 usa [literales de cadena formateados](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
nombre = "Jose"
print(f"mi nombre es {nombre}")
```

También puedes usar [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
nombre = "Jose"
print("mi nombre es {}".format(nombre))
```